Fault-tolerant CNOT gates
The controlled-not gate
$$
 CNOT = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
is important in many quantum computing protocols. So, given a quantum error-correcting code, it is of particular interest to have a fault tolerant implementations of $ CNOT $. For CSS codes this can be done with transversal $ CNOT $ CSS codes are the only stabilizer codes with transversal CNOT?.
But there are lots of stabilizer codes that are not CSS. Can anyone share a way to implement $ CNOT $ fault tolerantly on a non-CSS code? Or I suppose I would also be interested in a non-transversal but still fault-tolerant way of implementing $ CNOT $ on a CSS code.

I think the first thing to try is to find some way to generate entanglement between two code blocks: either find an entangling gate or find a way to deform two copies of your code into one entangled block

A non-transversal and fault-tolerant CNOT gate on a CSS code can be achieved through lattice surgery. See Section 4 of this paper.

Is there any way of using these ideas to make a fault-tolerant CNOT for a non-CSS code? I suppose for surface codes it makes sense to want a 2d way, like lattice surgery, to implement logical CNOT since doing transversal CNOT means basically stacking two surface code sheets like in figure 4 of the paper you linked, and stacking means 3d geometry which kind of defeats the 2d nearest neighbor interaction structure that is I guess the whole selling point of surface codes. This is honestly a reasonable answer but I'm really hoping for fault-tolerant CNOT on a non-CSS code.

I am not aware of one, sorry!

An easy extension would be codes locally equivalent to CSS codes. Then the gate that implements logical CNOT would be transversal CNOT conjugated by local Unitaries. An example would be the XZZX surface code. Though in that case some of the CNOT just get flipped.
